# I am not able to receive content when I run an automatic search

Tags: python, search

The last code I used without success is the following:

```
import requests

def googleSearch(qu):
    with requests.session() as c:
        url = 'https://www.google.com'
        qu = {'q': qu}
        urllink = requests.get(url, params=qu)
        x=urllink.url

        return x

x=googleSearch('translation')

import urllib.request
site=urllib.request.urlopen(x)
bytes=site.read()

text=bytes.decode("utf8")
print (text)
```

The expected relevant results would be:

hmtl stuff...
...
Google Tradutor
translate.google.pt › ...
O novo serviço gratuito da Google traduz instantaneamente palavras, expressões e até páginas da Web entre português e mais de 100 outros idiomas.

DeepL Translate ...

When I run the code, the expected content shown above is absent.

Is this a search engine trap?
Is it a code problem?

Comment: What is the content you receive? Do you get a result or an error? What happens if you do the same request from a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't find a 100% foolproof answer for this question but I found another way of implementing the same thing. You can, later on, mess with it, basically, we are going to use [BeautifulSoup4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) as a companion in this one:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def search(query): 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q="+str(query)).content, "html.parser")
    print(soup.prettify())

search("translation")
```

Later on, you can mess with the results. Here I'm just printing the prettified results. More info in BS4 can be found here: [Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: Aryan, It works very well, showing the urls which are the important thing.
But how to move to the next page?

Comment: To the query I added &start= it works too!